# Refactoring -where to start

Tags: refactoring

I have been assigned the task of identifying refactoring items. The purpose is to look at the presentation layer code and identify if there is any business logic coded there . Then identify what needs to be moved to Service / Business layer and what remains in presentation. 
The code at which I am looking at by design does not seem to use any of the design patterns; there are monolithic blocks of code with hardly any or useless comments. Are there any suggestions on how I can go about this task - approaches which work?

Currently I am trying to reverse engineer and understand which seems to be the hard way of achieving this task.
The purpose of this activity is to reuse the business logic .

Comment: My first thought - read "Code Complete" from Steve Mcconnell

Comment: @LudwigWensauer, no doubt that *Code Complete* is recommended reading in general, but what is specifically needed here is [*Working Effectively With Legacy Code*](http://www.amazon.com/Working-Effectively-Legacy-Michael-Feathers/dp/0131177052) by Michael Feathers.

Comment: @PéterTörök: You are right. I mixed them up

Answer (score 2):

Extracted from this nice video of Sandro Mancuso [1]

1. Start building tests from shortest to deepest branch.
2. Start refactoring from deepest to shortest branch,

[1] http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_embedded&v=_NnElPO5BU0#!

And, to guide you where to refactor, think about responsabilities: "Is the responsability of this code to do/know this other piece of code" ?

Answer (score 1):

Start by constructing a safety net - write unit tests for the existing classes and methods that demonstrate their proper operation.  If you're successful, you'll be able to refactor a bit at a time and still have passing unit tests as you go.

The unit tests will require a deep understanding on your part, which will come in handy when you refactor things.

Do it in small steps: refactor, test, repeat.

Another thought would be to try and introduce interfaces where you can.  These will act as fire breaks for change if you can isolate clients.

Get a good IDE that supports refactoring.  If you're writing Java, I'd recommend using IntelliJ.  It's the best IDE there is, and it supports refactoring very well.

Comment: More information on this answer here   http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Characterization_test